# How to add the align attribute to this line of code (inline) - HTML, JavaScript, and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caml

I am looking to insert the align attribute for centering column data.  I have several lines that are similar in composition to this:

`tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:42px;\">" + PriorityFormat($(this).attr("ows_Priority_x0020_Number"));  + "</td>";`

Is this doable?

Thanks!

Comment: `align` is deprecated.. you should use `text-align:center`. Just add this style along with the `width` style.

Comment: Great, thanks for the response!  I have almost zero experience with this, can you point me to where in the line I would need to add the text-align?  I've tried a few things but no success so far.  Thanks!

Comment: `"<td style=\"width:42px;text-align:center \">"`

Comment: Also you can use single quotes when they are encased in double quotes which saves the extra effort of escaping the double quotes.. `"<td style='width:42px;text-align:center'>"`

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you both, this worked exactly as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vega and Sushanth have answered this question in the comments above.  I used

`"<td style=\"width:42px;text-align:center \">"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `inline css` add class or target td by parent selector

Example:

```
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td class='td-center'>" + PriorityFormat($(this).attr("ows_Priority_x0020_Number")); + "</td>";
```

CSS

```
.td-center {width:42px; text-align:center}
```